# Collapsible table with data table plug-in

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, collapsable

I am using [data table plug-in](https://datatables.net/) for pagination..Now I want collapsible feature on click of every row of table...

This is a snippet of my code :

```
 <tr class="outer-tr">
     <td>1</td>
     <td>pppol</td>
     <td>Approved</td>
</tr>
<tr class="inner-tr"> 
       <td>show-hide</td> 
</tr>
```

And I am hiding/showing `inner-tr` on click of `outer-tr`.
But it gives an error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
```

I know this happens because of improper table format..

#### **Any suggestion to achieve collapsible table with data table plug-in???**

Comment: You need to provide you javascript for rendering the table

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery script in your code:

```js
$(function() {  
   $('.outer-tr').click(function() {
      $('.outer-tr td').toggleClass('visible');
   });
   $('.inner-tr').click(function() {
      $('.inner-tr td').toggleClass('visible');
   });
});
```

Also add a css style

```css
tr td{display: none;}
tr td.visible{display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the [JQuery DataTable documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) explains it here, provide your JS code if you need more help.